# Longest Common Prefix - getting runtime error

Tags: python

**Question:**

Write a function to find the longest common prefix string amongst an array of strings.

If there is no common prefix, return an empty string `""`.

**Example 1:**

```
Input: strs = ["flower","flow","flight"]
Output: "fl"
```

**Example 2:**

```
Input: strs = ["dog","racecar","car"]
Output: ""
```

**Explanation**: There is no common prefix among the input strings.

**Constraints:**

- `1 <= strs.length <= 200`
- `0 <= strs[i].length <= 200`
- `strs[i]` consists of only lowercase English letters.

**My Code**

```
def longestCommonPrefix(self, s: List[str]) -> str:
    st=''
    
    for i in range(len(s[0])):
        ch = s[0][i]
        match = True
        
        for j in range(1,len(s)):
            lj= len(s[j])
            if lj<i or ch != s[j][i]:
                match = False
                break
        if match == False:
            break
        else:
            st+=ch
    return st
```

**Runtime Error for following Input :**

**Input**

```
  ["ab", "a"]
```

Comment: all the time output will be 2 characters or 0 character? ex: `strs = ["abcd","abce","abc"]` for this example output should be `abc` or `ab` only?

Comment: output would be the string with maximum common prefix length between the list of strings   for example: `fl` in example 1 and  example: `['codeing' ,' code' , 'codzen'] `, common prefix is `'cod'`

Comment: you should debug first

Comment: can u please tell what is wrong in my code? I can easily get multiple solutions over internet..

Answer (score 1):

Take the first element, iterate over subsequent elements and determine the longest prefix

```
def solution( strs):
    if not strs:
        return ""
    res = strs[0]
    i = 1
    while i < len(strs):
        while strs[i].find(res) != 0:
            res = res[0:len(res) - 1]
        i += 1
    return res

# OUTPUT:
print(solution(["flower","flow","flight"]))  # fl
print(solution(["dog","racecar","car"]))    #
print(solution(  ["ab", "a"]))    # a
```

Comment: can u please tell why my code is not working.?

Comment: Your main problem is out of bounds, you determine at each length judgement if an exception is thrown, try changing lj < i to lj <= i , like this:  if lj <= i or ch ! = s[j][i],If there are still problems with the logic, try debugging to see if the output of each step meets your expectations

Answer (score 0):

first, you can get all occurrences; add in `dict` & then can work upon that `dict`

You can try:

```
strs = ["flower","flow","flight"]
collect_dict = {}
for data in strs:
    for d_index, d_data in enumerate(data):
        # import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
        inner_data = data[0:d_index + 1]
        if inner_data not in collect_dict:
            collect_dict[inner_data] = len([item for item in strs if item.startswith(inner_data)])

print(collect_dict)
keymax = max(zip(collect_dict.values(), collect_dict.keys()))[1]
print("max: " + keymax)
```

Output:

```
{'f': 3, 'fl': 3, 'flo': 2, 'flow': 2, 'flowe': 1, 'flower': 1, 'fli': 1, 'flig': 1, 'fligh': 1, 'flight': 1}
max: fl
```